# Why default value in Spring Value does not prevent the NULL error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have the following definition of my property in the Java Code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
...
@Value("#{sdProperties['is.test.server'] ?: false }") 
private boolean isTestServer = false;
```

Also in the XML configuration file I have:

```
<util:properties id="sdProperties">
    <prop key="sdzootest.server.url">${sdzootest.server.url}</prop>
    <prop key="is.test.server">${is.test.server}</prop>
</util:properties>
```

Still, I am getting the error if `is.test.server` is not specified in the property file:

> 2016-04-06 15:52:00,161 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   com.elasticpath.web.context.impl.EpContextConfigListener:69 - Caught
>   an exception.
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Invalid bean definition with name sdProperties defined in null: Could
>   not resolve placeholder 'is.test.server' in string value
>   "${is.test.server}"

Comment: I guess you need a default value for `<prop key="is.test.server">${is.test.server}</prop>`. Try `<prop key="is.test.server">${is.test.server:default}</prop>`

Answer (score 1):

`PlaceholderConfigurerSupport` has a special property `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders`

> If a configurer cannot resolve a placeholder, a
>   BeanDefinitionStoreException will be thrown. If you want to check
>   against multiple properties files, specify multiple resources via the
>   locations property. You can also define multiple configurers, each
>   with its own placeholder syntax. Use ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders to
>   intentionally suppress throwing an exception if a placeholder cannot
>   be resolved.

It's not clear how you setup placeholders support, so here several options:

```
<context:property-placeholder
        ignore-unresolvable="true"
        location="classpath:app.properties"/>
```

or

```
@Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ppc() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    return ppc;
}
```

Comment: I tried add context:property-placeholder in the configuration file - did not help.  I tried both sd.properties and app.properties.   About the 2nd suggestion - should it be in the @Configuration file?

Comment: @AlexNarinsky Yes, the method should be in the class marked `@Configuration` annotation